# Align two spans inside a td - One left and one right

Tags: css

I have a table. Inside the td's I have two span tags - the one span tag i want to align left, and the other right, but the td does not allow that:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><span>$</span><span>1000</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So I want the **$** to be aligned to the far **left** of the td and the **1000** to align to the far **right** of the td.

Is that possible?

Comment: A lot of answers there but looks like they are all saying the same thing. Apply a class and float them left and right

Comment: @Andrew Except that if this is the only content of the TD, you don't have to float the first one to the left.

Comment: Yip there are many ways of doing this and so far they all seem correct. but it can depend on how he is planning to use it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the following selector, without using extra classes:

```
td span:last-child{ /*not compatible with <=IE8*/
    color:green;
    float:right;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QR3kP/1/

---

For compatibility with IE7 and up use the CSS code below:

```
td span{
    float:right;
}
td span:first-child{ /* compatible to >=IE7 */
    float:left;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QR3kP/4/

---

Another approach is to right align the text inside the `<td>` and `float` only the first `<span>`:

```
td {
    text-align:right
}
td span:first-child {
    float:left;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QR3kP/29/

---

You can use a similar method with the above by using even less css declarations:

```
td span:first-child + span {
    float:right;
}
```

In the example above, the default `td` text align is left and you only select the sibling which is immediately preceded after the first `span`. Then you just `float` it to the right. Of course, you may use the `~` selector, which is the same thing **in this case**.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QR3kP/32/

---

See the compatibility chart here: http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/

See the CSS selectors here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: Just be aware that IE8 and below do not support `last-child`, although if you don't need IE8 and below support, this is by far the best.

Comment: @ajp15243 : I edited my answer for compatibility to IE7 and up. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

Probably best off doing it with floats.

```
<td colspan="5"><span class="left">$</span><span class="right">1000</span></td>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
    float: left
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NLZU5/

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to place a class onto each of the spans and apply the float to each ot the classes

HTML

```
<span class="left">$</span><span class="right">1000</span>
```

CSS

```
.left{float:left;}
.right{float:right;}
```

Comment: `.left`,`.right` is not semantic, how about `.sign`, `.value`

Comment: @JuanMendes semantics in css class naming? Any further reference to this?

Comment: @otinanai CSS class names should stand for the piece of data they represent, not for their look on the page. For example, some languages display the money sign on the right, and your CSS class name would not make sense in that case. A semantic class name means you could use an alternate style sheet to create a differnt look. See http://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/ and http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><span style="float:left;">$</span><span style="float:right;">1000</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eKEbF/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can set `float: left` on the `span` containing `$`, and `float: right` on the `span` containing your dollar amount.

Here's a simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YyEa6/) of it.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to float the first one to the left and the second one to the right

http://jsfiddle.net/L3QU2/1/

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">
      <span style="float:left">$</span>
      <span style="float:right">1000</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @DylanHayes I'm not suggesting inline styles, the question is not about how to properly separate CSS and HTML, this is just an example of how to get it done, and it tried to be concise in showing what CSS it takes with the least amount of changes to the OP's code. I wish I didn't have to add a disclaimer. The best answer is really otinanai's that doesn't need to add any markup to the HTML and can be succinctly put into a CSS snippet only

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `float` style for the spans using CSS classes.

```
<style>
    .left { float: left; }
    .right { float: right; }
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">
        <span class="left">$</span>
        <span class="right">1000</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I assume you were the first one who answered my question?